# Use custom TypeScript typing .d.ts in nextjs (Module not found: Can't resolve ...)

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm using JS library which does not provide @type definition for TypeScript, so I created my own `.d.ts` file. Let's call it `foo.d.ts`. My project structure looks like this:

```
...
.next/
pages/
...
typings/
    foo.d.ts
...
tsconfig.json
```

My VS Code has no problem with that definition and I can do import in my component, like:

```
import {Foo} from "foo";
```

But in run time I get this error in the browser console

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'foo'

I have tried to add

> "typeRoots": [
> "node_modules/@types",
> "typings"
> ]

to my `tsconfig.json` but it didn't help. I've also tried to explicitly add `foo.d.ts` to the include section where `next-env.d.ts` is added.

`foo.d.ts` looks like this:

```
declare module 'foo' {
    declare interface ValidationError {
        message?: string;
    }
    declare namespace Foo {
        class Bar {
            constructor(config: any, displayErrorsCallback: (data: ValidationError[]) => void, onSubmitTriggered: () => void);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update** (added tsconfig)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "typings"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you actually installed `foo`? .d.ts files just declare types and assume the package is present, you still have to `npm install` the package itself.

Comment: I’m importing foo.js with <script .../> so in runtime it works.

Comment: In my d.ts file I declare module “foo”, I thought that means that I have to use import “foo”?

Comment: @pastorgluk You're correct, I missed that part when I first read the question. Could you add your `tsconfig.json` please?

Comment: sure, added tsconfig to the question

Comment: Why are you importing it via script tag? Use the package manager.

Comment: @pastorgluk have you managed to solve this issue? Interesting thing is if I use the same logic for a new create-react-app app it all works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Just add `.d` after the file name, so import your type definition as `import {Foo} from "foo.d";`
Whenever importing `*.d.ts`, import them like that, no need to edit configs.

Comment: This works, but is this the way it's supposed to work? It seems like it's just treating the .d.ts file as a regular typescript file, so isn't this the same as just renaming the file from foo.d.ts to just foo.ts?

Comment: also curious about this (now that Next.js in v14+). No official documentation discusses best practices on this as yet.